# Draw a line between two elements with hover

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I've seen a number of examples on how to do this, but none of them do what I need done.

What I want done, is when a certain image (it could be wrapped in an individual div if needed) is hovered over, it draws a line from the center of that image to the center of another image (or potentially from the center of the first image to the center of several other images), and on mouse out, it returns to the original state.

I tried using HTML5 canvas, but when I tried to even draw a line on the canvas while shifting HTML (the images) over the canvas, the images covered the canvas and line drawn. When I tried to change the z-index of the canvas, it worked except that the canvas covered over the HTML and made the existing on-hover image changes not work.

I've found regular JS examples of drawing lines, but they all rely on knowing the exact points to draw from...is there any way to do this by having the exact points be calculated by the JS and not needing to be hard-coded in? With the on-hover displaying the drawn lines?

Comment: Make the images part of the canvas.

Comment: If you want to get the drawing feeling you should continue with canvas. If a hidden div with border would satisfy your need, let us know

Answer (score 1):

How about this alternative to highlight connections between images (if your design allows):

- Add a background canvas that is wide/high enough for all your html img's to fit.
- Add your html img's on top of the canvas (not as part of the canvas).
- On hover, draw connecting lines on the canvas & put a highlight border around your connected imgs.
- On leaving, clear the canvas connecting lines and remove the img borders.

[image: Before Hover][image: During Hover]

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4n9GK/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    #img1{position:absolute; left:30px; top:30px; }
    #img2{position:absolute; left:200px; top:180px; }
    #img3{position:absolute; left:30px; top:330px; }
    #img4{position:absolute; left:200px; top:30px; }
    #img5{position:absolute; left:30px; top:180px; }
    #img6{position:absolute; left:200px; top:330px; }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle="skyblue";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);


    $(".connectable").hover(

        function(){connectGroup(this);},
        function(){unconnectGroup(this);}

    );

    function connectGroup(element){

        var $element=$(element);

        var hubId=$element.attr("id");
        var p=$element.position();
        var hubX=p.left;
        var hubY=p.top;
        var hubW=$element.width();
        var hubH=$element.height();
        ctx.fillStyle="green";
        ctx.fillRect(hubX-3,hubY-3,hubW+6,hubH+6);

        var group=$element.attr("data-group");

        var g="img[data-group='"+group+"']"

        var $group=$(g);

        var notG="img:not("+g+")";
        var $hidden=$(notG);
        $hidden.fadeOut();

        $group.each(function(){

            var $groupMember=$(this);

            var id=$groupMember.attr("id");

            if(id!=hubId){
                var p=$groupMember.position();
                var x=p.left;
                var y=p.top;
                var w=$groupMember.width();
                var h=$groupMember.height();
                ctx.fillStyle="green";
                ctx.strokeStyle="green";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(hubX+hubW/2,hubY+hubH/2);
                ctx.lineTo(x+w/2,y+h/2);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fillRect(x-3,y-3,w+6,h+6);
            }

        });

    }

    function unconnectGroup(element){
        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        // show the hidden images
        $("img").show();
    }



}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=330 height=450></canvas>
    <img id="img1" class="connectable" data-group="1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png" width=100 height=100/>
    <img id="img2" class="connectable" data-group="1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png" width=100 height=100/>
    <img id="img3" class="connectable" data-group="1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png" width=100 height=100/>
    <img id="img4" class="connectable" data-group="2" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/ship.png" width=100 height=100/>
    <img id="img5" class="connectable" data-group="2" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/ship.png" width=100 height=100/>
    <img id="img6" class="connectable" data-group="2" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/ship.png" width=100 height=100/>
    <h3>Hover over image to show connections</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alright...I think I can figure out how to do the background canvas and use CSS to position the HTML on top of the canvas (I did it a few hours ago). But, how would I go about the on hover and connecting it with the canvas (and then the on leave clearing the canvas)? What would be ideal is if I could assign each img a data-connection and a data-id attr and if one img is hovered, it draws a line to the image(s) that contain the data-id attr that would correspond with the data-connection attr, i.e., data-connection='2', data-id='1' would draw a line to say, data-con='1', data-id='1', or something

Comment: I've added example code to my answer.  Explanation: Upon hover, (1) Get the target element, (2) Get the data-group for that element, (3) Get all members of that data-group (4) Hide any images that are not a member of that data-group, (5) use the canvas (under the images) to draw highlight borders and lines connecting from the target image to all data-group elements in its group.  Upon leaving (1) clear the canvas--which clears the highlighting and connectors, (2) re-show the previously hidden images.  Disclaimer: I used jQuery--it would be madness to try without it!

Answer (score 1):

As an unconventional alternative you can give [this library](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm) a try. It's a pre-HTML5-canvas oldie-but-still-goodie. It has an ability to turn any DIV into a pseudo "canvas", you can have any HTML elements inside of this DIV and do all kinds of drawing between them.

For example if you define your "canvas" like this:

```
<div id="myCanvas" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

You can init the library, set the color, stroke size and draw line like this:

```
var jg = new jsGraphics("myCanvas");

jg.setColor("#0000FF");
jg.setStroke(2);
jg.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

jg.paint();
```

It ain't HTML5 canvas, but it's a "canvas" you can place DOM elements directly inside of and draw there as well.

Here's a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rs5eY/1/ wave the mouse over top image.

Answer (score 0):

as @Boaz suggests, you will ideally want to make the images part of the canvas, while keeping tract of where you drew them in some set of javascript variables.  Then you can programmatically draw lines from image to image, since everything would be connected on the same instance of canvas.  Is there some reason that you cannot do this?

Comment: Well, I'm not really drawing images (am I?), and the images have JavaScript already included in them: `<a href="page.php?x=1895&y=2015"><img style='background:url(images/tile_2.png)' class='xyz' data-alt-src='images/X.png' data-name=' &nbsp; ' src="images/tile_2.png" /></a>` and when on hover, the image URL is already changed to the alt-src and the data-name is then displayed in an TD...and as far as I can tell, I can't easily put the existing code (since there's around 100 of those sorts of images) in a canvas, or can I?